# Regex which matches all alpha numeric chars and zero or one '@' symbol

Tags: regex

I need a regex which matches all alpha numeric chars and zero or one '@' symbol in any part of the string, so:-

```
Ab01@ - match
Ab0@1 - match
@Ab01 - match
```

here's what I have:-

```
/^[A-Za-z0-9]+@{0,1}$/
```

The above matches the '@' when it's at the end of the string but doesn't match when it's at the start or in the middle, for example

```
@Ab01 - no match
Ab@01 - no match
```

I've tried removing the `^` & `$` indicating start and end of the expression - but this allows more than one match of the `@` which is not what I want.

Comment: Please also add a tag for the language or tool you need the regex for, as each has its own rules and quirks.

Comment: Just use `^(?!(?:[^@]*@){2})[A-Za-z0-9@]+$`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the @ can be there only a single time, you can match optional chars from `[A-Za-z0-9]` and optionally match an @ in between.

If you don't want to match empty strings and a negative lookahead is supported:

```
^(?!$)[A-Za-z0-9]*@?[A-Za-z0-9]*$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/nXbytp/1)

If there has to be at least a single char of `[A-Za-z0-9]` present, you could also use

```
^(?=@?[A-Za-z0-9])[A-Za-z0-9]*@?[A-Za-z0-9]*$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/HSoKvh/1)

Comment: Slick. Regex on steroids. Thanks.

Comment: Do you even need the: `(?!$)`  ? What data would regex without it not satisfy?

Comment: @JGFMK If could match an empty string as all the parts are optional.

Comment: Nice. I like that.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively maybe use:

```
^(?!.*@.*@)[A-Za-z\d@]+$
```

See the [demo](https://regex101.com/r/eZUiuJ/3).

---

- `^` - Start string ancor.
- `(?!.*@.*@)` - Negative lookahead to prevent multiple "@".
- `[A-Za-z\d@]+` - One or more characters from the specified character class.
- `$` - End string ancor.